# copying value after moving to next cell

Tags: excel, vba

hi everyone
 i have two workbooks one named "a.xlsm" and the other is "b.xlsx". File b.xlsx located in different folder named "b". What i am trying to do is copy cell in row A in a.xlsm into cell A2 in b.xlsx after moving it to next cell.
here is my code

```
    Private Sub CopyNota_Click()

        On Error GoTo errorhandler:
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        Dim strpath As String
        Dim copysheet As Worksheet
        Dim pastesheet As Worksheet

        Set copysheet = Worksheets("sheet3")
        Set pastesheet = Worksheets("sheet5")
        strpath = "E:\b\"
        Filename = Dir(strpath & "b.xlsx")

        If IsEmpty(Range("B2")) Then
            Workbooks("b.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet3").Range("H2:J2").Copy destination:=Range("B2:D2")
            Range("A2").Copy destination:=Workbooks("b.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A2")
            Workbooks("b.xlsx").Save
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Else
            Workbooks("b.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet3").Range("H2:J2").Copy
            Worksheets("sheet5").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Workbooks("b.xlsx").Save
    'below is the code that didn't work
            Workbooks("b.xlsx").Worksheets("sheet3").Range("A2").Value _
            = Worksheets("sheet5").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value

    End If

        errorhandler:
        If Err.Number = "52" Then
            MsgBox "Open The Workbooks First!!!"
            Exit Sub
        End If

        End Sub
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't need that if statement:

```
    If IsEmpty(Range("B2")) Then
```

If B2 is empty then it is the offset of end(xlup).offset(1,0) anyway.

Which workbook is active while the code is running? The code assumes it is WorkbookA but I thought it worthwhile to check with you.

Also it looks like you don't have Workbook B open?? Things will be easier if you open it but still doable if you don't

Lastly with regards to your specific question,

```
Worksheets("sheet5").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value
```

will always be blank because it is last row of data offset by 1 row

Comment: both of the workbooks is active while the code is running, so how i can get the value for "A2" after the code is moving to the next cell and is it possible to get some value in vba while the workbooks is closed?

Comment: Without knowing your data or goals I would imagine for starters you need to remove Offset(1, 0). from the row quoted above? Also I can't post the info on interacting with a closed workbook as I am not at my normal PC (with my code snippets) however from memory it used the Excel 4 language somehow from within VBA. This will hook you up. http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=454

Comment: here is my data
a.xlsm the data begin in cell A2
No     Name     Date     Komp
b.xlsx
in cell H2:J2 contain name date and komp and in cell A2 is null at the begining
my first goal is i want to check cell B2 in a.xlsx if it's empty then copy the value in range H2:J2 into a.xlsm and place in in cell B2:D2 and if not it will move to the next cell and place in there
my second goal is after the method above is worked i want to get the number in a.xlsm and place it in cell A2 in b.xlsx and it's value will automatically changed every time i push the button